# Mistake in Paper about LMI characterisation of trigonometric polynomial curve?

Tags: trigonometry, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, convex-hulls, linear-matrix-inequality

The following is taken from [Efficient Large-Scale Filter/Filterbank Design via LMI Characterization of Trigonometric Curves](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4291872) by Hoang Duong Tuan, Tran Thai Son, Ba-Ngu Vo, and Truong Q. Nguyen

Consider the curve
$$
C_{a,b}: =\{(1, \cos(t), \cos(2 t), \ldots, \cos(n t))^{T}: \cos t\in[\cos a, \cos b]\subset[-1,1]\}\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}
$$
(I will only consider $a = \pi$, $b = 0$, so we take all $0 \le t < 2 \pi$)
and define
\begin{align*}
T_{k}(t)
& = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \cos(t) \\ \ldots \\ \cos(k t) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \cos(t) & \ldots & \cos(k t) \end{pmatrix}^T \\
& = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \cos(t) & \ldots & \cos(k t) \\
\cos(t) & \frac{1}{2}(\cos(2 t) + 1) & \ldots & \frac{1}{2}[\cos((k + 1)t) - \cos((k - 1)t)] \\
\cos(kt) & {1\over 2}\left[\cos((k+1)t)+\cos((k-1)t)\right] & \ldots& {1 \over 2} (\cos(2kt)+1)
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
The matrix $T_k(y)$ is obtained from $T_k(t)$ via $\cos(ht) \longleftrightarrow y_{h}$ for $0 \le h \le k$, that is, we have
$$
T_k(y)
:= \begin{pmatrix} y_0 & y_1 & \ldots & y_k \\
y_1 & \frac{1}{2}(y_{2 k} + 1) & \ldots & \frac{1}{2}(y_{k + 1} - y_{k - 1}) \\
y_k & {1\over 2}\left(y_{k + 1}+y_{k - 1}\right) & \ldots& {1 \over 2} (y_{2k}+1)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Furthermore, let  $T_{k, \ell}(t) := \cos(\ell t) T_k(t)$ and $T_{k, \ell}(y)$ be obtained via the same transformation.
Lastly, let
$$
F_{k}^{a,b}(y) = (\cos(b) +\cos(a)){T}_{1,k-1}(y)-{1\over 2}T_{2,k-1}(y)-\left({1\over 2}+\cos(a) \cos(b)\right)T_{k-1}(y)
$$

The authors now claim that (Thm. 3, bottom right on p. 4396)
$$
\text{conv}(C_{a, b})
= \begin{cases}
\left\{(y_{0}, y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n})^T:T_{k}(y)\ge 0, \ F_{k}^{a,b}(y)\ge 0, y_{0}=1\right\}, & n=2k \\
\left\{(y_{0}, y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n})^T:\cos(b) T_{k}(y)\ge T_{1,k}(y)\ge\cos(a) T_{k}(y), y_{0}=1\right\}, & n=2k+1.
\end{cases}
$$

**My question:**
If $n = 3$, we have $k = 1$ and (in the special case that $a = \pi$, $b = 0$ and thus $\cos(a) = - 1$, $\cos(b) = 1$) we have
\begin{align}
\text{conv}(C_{\pi, 0})
& = \{ (1, y_1, y_2, y_3): T_1(y) \ge y_1 T_1(y) \ge - T_1(y) \} \\
& = \{ (1, y_1, y_2, y_3): (1 \pm y_1) T_1(y) \ge 0 \} \\
& = \{ (1, y_1, y_2, y_3): T_1(y) \ge 0 \} \\
& = \{ (1, y_1, y_2, y_3): y_2 + 1 \ge y_1^2 \},
\end{align}
but as $y_3$ is not present in any entry of $T_1$, this would mean that $y_3$ can be arbitrary, which is clearly false. What am I missing?

Comment: It mean "you could **step** through it for $n = 2k+1$" (a word got lost, I assume). It's probably best (given your final example/question) to do it for the case $n = 3, k = 1$.